# Question count and answer count appear on the same line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looking at the [user page of a single-answer-no-questions user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7716/ako), I'm seeing the question count and answer count on the same line - shouldn't they be separate?

Also, the distance from the left edge is different for that line and the start of tags (and badges) count.

> [image: user page screenshot]

Browser is Firefox 4.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: +1 for memetic obedience.

Comment: No repro on IE7. ...stop laughing, that's what those terminals have installed. :P

Comment: No repro on IE8 on XP.

Comment: No repro in Chrome 10 on Win 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro. the fix will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the page with Firebug, the issue is that all.css is overriding the profile css sheet. Both contain the css element of "margin-left" for ".unit-stats-table", and the one in all.css is labeled !important.  Removing the !important solves the problem, and does not seem to create any other errors (at least on this page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing this in chrome. Is it Firefox specific?

Comment: Don't know if it's specific, but from the comments it doesn't appear in IE or Chrome.

Comment: I have the issue and I'm using Firefox, so sounds like it might be firefox only. I tested it in IE as well (shutters) and it's fine there.